# microk8s kubeflow dashboard access - Failed to exchange authorization code with token: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, microk8s, openid-dex

After installing microk8s and then enabling kubeflow I'm given the username, password and link to Kubeflow dashboard. Then I access the dashboard as expected and all is well. BUT after restarting my machine and executing microk8s start I can no longer get to the kubeflow dashboard.

All the pods start fine and then I go to access the dashboard and get:

```
Access to 10.64.140.44.nip.io was denied
You don't have authorisation to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

Looking at the kubernetes logs for the pod/container oidc-gatekeeper-xxxxx / oidc-gatekeeper I have:

```
level=error msg="Failed to exchange authorization code with token: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized\nResponse: {\"error\":\"invalid_client\",\"error_description\":\"Invalid client credentials.\"}" ip=10.1.252.88 request="/authservice/oidc/callback?code=ipcb55gymqsy5pcgjn7eaenad&state=MTYyMjYzNjE4OHxFd3dBRURoMVZtSm9Wak4yUXpWQlYxZ3pPVWs9fPTKezGok06ig6bjtYvWt9sqhzaCpO_xhSMeTUFDL81j"
```

And for pod/container dex-auth-5d9bf87db9-rjtm8 / dex-auth:

```
level=info msg="invalid client_secret on token request for client: authservice-oidc"
```

Only by removing microk8s altogether and reinstalling everytime I restart my machine can I get this working again which is obviously not workable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, why is this post tagged with 'istio' ?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to resolve the issue but I'm not 100% sure which action resolved it.

I tried using Firefox rather than Chrome and noticed some documentation used IP http://10.64.140.43.nip.io/ rather than http://10.64.140.44.nip.io/.

Having been refused access as above for http://10.64.140.44.nip.io/ I found http://10.64.140.43.nip.io/ took me straight into the dashboard.

I restarted my machine to see if it was just the IP (note: checking "microk8s kubectl get services -n kubeflow" specified 10.64.150.44 as the external IP), but this time http://10.64.140.44.nip.io/ just gave me the dex log in screen and after logging in took me to the dashboard without issue.

Perhaps I just did something wrong somewhere, I'm not sure and can't check now it works as it should. Apologise if you get here with the issue and this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. Solution for me was to enable dns, istio, and storage first. Wait until the pods were running, and then enable Kubeflow. Then make sure to port-forward using the istio-system namespace with the istio-ingressgateway pod. Kubeflow also makes a istio-ingressgateway pod, but connecting to that yielded the error. Per [Kubeflow guide](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/central-dash/overview/)